# Finishing a Garage

Tags: garage

[image: IMage number 2][image]I am a new home owner and Looking to finish my garage, It has reinforced 2 by 4s due to previous termite damage.  It is a detached garage. From what I understand there is only the outer shell of the garage but nothing else.

I have to first insulate it, then put vapor and I guess sheet rock?

I am not really sure where to start, or what insulation to buy or how to even apply it? If anyone knows I would love to get your opinion on how to tackle this myself..

[image]
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApNsx.jpg)

Comment: Unless you are heating or cooling it, insulation and vapor barrier are optional. Well, "finishing" it is also optional - what is your actual goal here? To see sheetrock rather than framing? To heat and/or cool the building?

Comment: And if you do want to heat/cool, a **lot** will depend on where you are (Florida (hot & humid), Arizona (hot & dry), New York (hot in the summer, cold in the winter) are very different. What kind of electrical feed do you have, if any?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In what way are the 2x4s "reinforced"? Some pictures of this would help a lot. Just about any type of insulation will work fine for you. Rockwool is particularly fire resistant (it's literally made of rock), fiberglass is pretty fire resistant, too. Spray foam works _really_ well, but is _really_ expensive. There are all sorts of options and which to use is something of an opinion. My opinion is that Rockwool is nicer to work with than fiberglass, but others may disagree. Also, asking for opinions is off topic because there is no "right" opinion...

Comment: At a very basic level for a garage that already keeps the rain/snow off the vehicles (or junque you store in it to prevent parking vehicles in it) with no further conditioning intended, a coat of white paint (on the interior of the sheathing and framing) will brighten the place up.

Comment: Sorry everyone, first time using this site.  I just want to have the garage as possible storage space, or a spot to put backstock ( diapers, toilet paper, soap ). Eventually in 5-7 years I will be looking to sell my home and would love to have this garage presentable for such a time if it occurs.